# How do i structure a string array in ajax and pass it to asp?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

In my project, I want to use ajax for the communication between JS and ASP. However, I got 500 error in it.

JSON string in JS ajax:

```
 {lists: [{'ID': 'a95fed0d-c1e4-45e8-2cd2-e5d7f099a111', 'colour': 'red'}, {'ID': 'a95fed0d-c1e4-45e8-2cd2-e5d7f099a222', 'colour': 'green'}]}
```

C#:

```
 [WebMethod]
 public static string GetCurrentTime(List<string> lists)
 {
     return "text string" ;
 }
```

FULL AJAX:

```
var dataJson = "{lists: [{'ID': 'a95fed0d-c1e4-45e8-2cd2-e5d7f099a111', 'colour': 'red'}, {'ID': 'a95fed0d-c1e4-45e8-2cd2-e5d7f099a222', 'colour': 'green'}]}";
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: URL,
            data: dataJson ,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
function OnSuccess(response) {
        console.log(response.d);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `JSON.stringify` as below with a object instead of `List<string>`,

```
var dataJson = {lists: [{'ID': 'a95fed0d-c1e4-45e8-2cd2-e5d7f099a111', 'colour': 'red'}, {'ID': 'a95fed0d-c1e4-45e8-2cd2-e5d7f099a222', 'colour': 'green'}]};
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: URL,
            data: JSON.stringify(dataJson),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
function OnSuccess(response) {
        console.log(response.d);
    }
```

C#

```
public class Data { 
        public string ID {get;set;}
         public string colour {get;set;}   // This can be renamed into Pascal case here and in the json
       }

[WebMethod]
 public static string GetCurrentTime(List<Data> lists)
 {
     return "text string" ;
 }
```

Comment: I have updated the code. Please try. It should not be `List<string>' as your json has object array and not string array.

Comment: I print the error in console. It says `Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]`

Comment: Yes, thats what I told in my above comment. Please try my updated code for both Javascript and C#

Comment: So, how to convert my json string to json? I have tried `JSON.parse("{lists: [{'ID': 'a95fed0d-c1e4-45e8-2cd2-e5d7f099a111', 'colour': 'red'}]}")`, but i return syntaxError... (the json string is received from another site and it is type of string original)

Comment: Okay, can you try first without `JSON.stringify` but with my `List<Data>` example. Your string has `"{lists: [{` but it should be something like, `"{'lists': [{` which basically `JSON.stringify` will do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>

        $(function () {
            //alert('jQuery');
            var URL = 'WebForm1.aspx/GetCurrentTime';
            var dataJson = { lists: [{ 'ID': 'a95fed0d-c1e4-45e8-2cd2-e5d7f099a111', 'colour': 'red' }, { 'ID': 'a95fed0d-c1e4-45e8-2cd2-e5d7f099a222', 'colour': 'green'}] };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: URL,
                data: JSON.stringify(dataJson),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
            function OnSuccess(response) {
                console.log(response.d);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

.cs

```
public class ListObject
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string colour { get; set; }
    }
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        [WebMethod]
        public static string GetCurrentTime(object lists)
        {

            List<ListObject> objects = new List<ListObject>();
            Object[] results = (Object[])lists;

            foreach (Dictionary<String, Object> result in results)
            {
                var properties = result as Dictionary<string, object>;
                List<String> propertyNames = new List<string>();
                String ID=String.Empty;
                String colour = String.Empty;
                int idFlag = 0;
                foreach (var p in properties)
                {
                    if (idFlag == 0)
                    {
                        ID= p.Value.ToString();
                        idFlag = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        colour = p.Value.ToString();
                    }
                    //String sjs = p.ToString().Replace("[","").Replace("]","").Split(',')[1];

                }

                     objects.Add(new ListObject
                {
                    ID = ID,
                    colour = colour
                });
            }


            return "text string";
        }
    }
```